# How to style email template in magento2?

Tags: magento2, email

How to style email template? I want to override email variable value and change style according without element inline style used. Is there possible to complie email's less files with grunt.

**How to compile email style?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please follow below step to compile **`email.less`**

> 1. copy **_email-extend.less** folder from **vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/source/_email-extend.less** and put under **app/design/frontend/vendor(packagename)/your-theme(custom theme)/web/css/source/**
> 2. open **root/dev/tools/grunt/configs/theme.js** and put following code in it (configure your theme in **theme.js**)

```
    theme: {
    area: 'frontend',
    name: 'vendor/your-theme',
    locale: 'en_US',
    files: [
        'css/styles-m',
        'css/styles-l',
        'css/email',
        'css/email-inline',            

    ],
    dsl: 'less'
```

1. Clean **root/var/ and pub/static** folder.
2. Run grunt **exec:theme** (your-theme)
3. Run **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**
4. Run **grunt watch:theme** (your-theme)
5. Modify "_email-extend.less", now it is compile through grunt.

Comment: It's working fine. Great Work!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the non-inline style I can recommend reading this article and paragraph [Magento 2 Dev Docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html#non-inline-styles)

If you want the non-inline styles to work, then these must be in a `<style type="text/css"></style>` tag for them to work. You need to make sure the `{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}` or the code below is in your email template.

```
<style type="text/css">
    {{var template_styles|raw}}
</style>
```

**UPDATE**
Sorry misunderstood your question, this link should help you for this [Magento Dev Docs Grunt](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html)

Comment: I want to compile `_email-variables.less` and `_email-extend.less` compile with grunt. how can i do that ?

Comment: Did you have a look at this one http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html

Comment: I know how to compile with grunt but, these two file are not compile with grunt.

Comment: The files are even mentioned there so I don´t get why these wouldn´t get compiled in your case